# Rails Cast array item to Object model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, casting

hi i am trying to cast an item from my array of objects to model but I can not do

this is what throws me off when I print the variable data

this is my controller

```
 def add_autorizador_operario
    @auto=AutorizacionIncidencia.new({:fam_subcat_incidencia_id=>'3'})
    @auto=AutorizacionIncidencia.new({:fam_subcat_incidencia_id=>'2'})
    @arr_autorizaciones=  Array.new
    @arr_autorizaciones << @auto
    @arr_autorizaciones << @auto2
  end
```

and this is my view print

```
 <% @arr_autorizaciones.each do |dat| %>
       <%= dat[:autorizacion_incidencia].to_s  %>
      <% end %>
```

how i cast to AutorizacionIncidencia model

Comment: what does `@auto.autorizacion_incidencia` return?

Comment: The question is not clear enough to tell anything - what are you trying to achieve? What is expected result and what is the current behaviour? What do you mean by `converting array to model`? Also, you probably have a typo, as you're assigning `@auto` twice and then append `@auto2` to the array - this will throw `undefined method [] for nil` in your view.

Comment: `dat` already is an `AutorizacionIncidencia`. Nothing to do here. You can now print its attributes, `<%= dat.fam_subcat_incidencia_id %>` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is, I restart my machine and found with this line

```
<%= dat.fam_subcat_incidencia_id %>
```